# Torque on a spool of thread

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, torque

[image: Torque on a spool of thread]

Here is a problem I encountered in my physics class. I was thinking that the answer was **a**, but the answer key says that the answer is **d**. Could someone explain this problem to me and the concept of translational vs rotational vs rolling motion?

Comment: Why did you think the answer was **a**? Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: See similar questions [How to find the acceleration of a spool pulled by a force and its work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/475896) and [How does this spool have an angular acceleration opposite to its acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221133)